# how can I use an enum to replace several fields? How can I pass these values to an interface?

Tags: java, class, interface, enums

I have a class which 4 fields which I need to be able to set and get. I have to use setters and getters, but also instead of using regular fields, have to use an enum. This concept confuses me - considering the fields arent necessarily constants. I'll give an example

If we call the class Bear, the 4 fields may be:
name, type, nickname, homeZoo.
Note all the fields are of the same type.

I need to have methods setname(string) getname() etc.

On top of my confusion with enum, I also have to be able to pass the set value of one of the fields to an interface - would I have to implement the interface on bear? Or is there some way to give the value to a method in the interfeace since an enum is a public static final sort of thing.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like there are a lot of moving parts to this question.  We may be able to understand it better & offer more help with a code example.

Comment: Can you give more on why you feel you need these things?  I think the reason you are having trouble with Enums is that they aren't the correct solution for your problem, but it's hard to tell with the restrictions you've given.  Why do you *have* to have getters and setters?  If this is a homework assignment and has these restrictions, you should say so.  If not, you should say why you feel you need it done this way (assuming you want real help and not just some answer that answers your question without fixing your problem)

Comment: Enum types are not much different from regular classes such as String. I don't understand the problem, just replace the name of the regular class with the name of the enum.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but I couldn't fit it in a comment.  Perhaps this will help you clarify your question if nothing else.

Classes generally DO something different in your implementation than other classes.  For instance, if you have a Bear class you'd expect it to do something different from a Dog class (a Dog can wag, maybe a Bear can charge).

If, however, you are just tracking Bears for a zoo and you are also tracking Lions, what you want is probably an Animals class that contains "Bear" or "Lion" as a field.

Now, in that case Bear and Lion could be enums that are stored in the Animal class to tell what kind of critter the animal is.  Is this what you were intending?  If so your Animal class would have a setBreed and your enum would be a Breed {Bear, Lion, ...}.

Answer (score 0):

enums generally cannot replace several fields.

They are used to attempt to force an argument of a method (or similar) to accept **only** specific pre-defined values.

Consider using an enum when a variable can be one of only 3 or so different values.

If it can only be 2 different values you can use a boolean. If you think you might add a third option in the future, perhaps use an enum.

The classic examples of enums are playing cards.

```
enum Colour{BLACK , RED}
enum Rank{A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K}
enum Suit{SPADES,HEARTS,CLUBS,DIAMONDS}
```

A card with a rank outside the above limited set does not make sense. So an enum can be used to represent it.

You could declare an interface

```
interface CheckSuit
{
    public boolean checkSuit( Suit suit );
}
```

and a class that implements it.

```
class CheckSpade implements CheckSuit
{
    public boolean checkSuit( Suit suit )
    {
        return ( suit == Suit.SPADES );
    }
}
```

and some code that uses it. Here we declare suitChecker to be an instance of interface CheckSuit and after assigning it to be a new CheckSpade we can only interact with it polymorphically as a CheckSuit. We don't know what it is (at least without using instanceof or similar)

```
CheckSuit suitChecker = new CheckSpade();
Suit s = Suit.SPADES;
Suit d = Suit.DIAMONDS;
System.out.println( "s: " + suitChecker.checkSuit( s ) );
System.out.println( "d: " + suitChecker.checkSuit( d ) );
```